# Python library for awk-like file manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, awk

I recently published a library for advanced awk-like file manipulation in Python 3. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/SimoneBronzini/awk/blob/master/awk.py) and [here](https://github.com/SimoneBronzini/awk) is the documentation. It is also available for download from pip (`pip install awk`). I would like to know if the code is well designed and how it can be improved to enforce readability and code reuse. I would also like to know if efficiency can be improved keeping in mind that it should be able to handle large files.

```
import re
from itertools import zip_longest
from collections import OrderedDict


class FileNotOpenException(Exception):
    pass


class FieldNotFoundException(Exception):
    pass


DEFAULT_FIELD_SEP = r'\s+'


def _DEFAULT_FIELD_FUNC(field_key, field):
    return field


def _DEFAULT_FIELD_FILTER(field_key, field):
    return True


def _DEFAULT_RECORD_FUNC(NR, record):
    return record


def _DEFAULT_RECORD_FILTER(NR, record):
    return True


class Record(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialises a Record object"""
        self._field_dict = {}
        self._field_list = []
        self._key_list = []
        self._iterator = None

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Allows access to fields in the following forms:
        - record[2]  # column indices start from 0
        - record[4:7:2]  # same as above
        - record['$4']  # same as record[3]
        - record['mykey']  # columns are indexed based on header, if present
        """
        try:
            try:
                return self._field_dict[key]
            except (KeyError, TypeError):  # nonexisting key or slice, respectively
                return self._field_list[key]
        except IndexError:
            raise FieldNotFoundException('No field {} in record'.format(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        """should never be done manually, better create a new record than modifying an existing one"""
        self._field_dict[key] = val
        self._key_list.append(key)
        self._field_list.append(val)

    def add(self, val):
        """should never be done manually, better create a new record than modifying an existing one"""
        self['${}'.format(len(self._field_list) + 1)] = val

    def fields(self):
        """returns a generator of the record's fields"""
        yield from self._field_list

    def keys(self):
        """returns a generator of the record's keys"""
        yield from self._key_list

    def __iter__(self):
        """returns an iterator over the record's keys"""
        self._iterator = iter(self._key_list)
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """returns the next (key, field) pair. If a header was provided, the key corresponds to the header
        otherwise it is of the form $1, $2, ..., $NF"""
        try:
            next_key = next(self._iterator)
            return next_key, self._field_dict[next_key]
        except StopIteration:
            self._iterator = None
            raise StopIteration

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._field_list)

    @property
    def NF(self):
        """same as awk's NF variable"""
        return len(self)

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(len(self))

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Record({})'.format(', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(key, self._field_dict[key]) for key in self._key_list]))


class Reader(object):

    # TODO: add field type
    def __init__(self,
                 filename,
                 fs=DEFAULT_FIELD_SEP,
                 header=False,
                 max_lines=None,
                 field_filter=_DEFAULT_FIELD_FILTER,
                 record_filter=_DEFAULT_RECORD_FILTER):
        """Initialises a Reader
        Arguments:
        filename -- the name of the file to parse
        Keyword arguments:
        fs -- regex that separates the fields
        header -- if set to True, the reader interprets the first line of the file as a header.
                  In this case every record is returned as a dictionary and every field in the header
                  is used as the key of the corresponding field in the following lines
        max_lines -- the maximum number of lines to read
        field_filter -- a function f(key, field) which is applied to the field.
                        If it returns a falsy value, the field is not included in the record.
                        default: lambda *args: True
        record_filter -- a function f(NR, field) which is applied to the record.
                         If it returns a falsy value, the record is not returned.
                         default: lambda *args: True
        """
        self.filename = filename
        self.header = header
        self.fs = fs
        self.max_lines = max_lines
        self.field_filter = field_filter
        self.record_filter = record_filter
        self._compiled_fs = re.compile(fs)
        self._openfile = None
        self._keys = None

    @property
    def keys(self):
        """returns the keys of the header if present, otherwise None"""
        return self._keys

    def __enter__(self):
        self._openfile = open(self.filename)
        self.lines = 0
        if self.header:
            first_line = next(self._openfile).rstrip()
            self._keys = tuple(self._compiled_fs.split(first_line))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._openfile.close()
        self.lines = 0
        self._openfile = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def _get_record(self, fields):
        record = Record()

        if self.header:
            if len(fields) > len(self._keys):
                zip_func = zip
            else:
                zip_func = zip_longest

            for key, value in zip_func(self._keys, fields):
                if self.field_filter(key, value):
                    record[key] = value
        else:
            # indexes start from 0
            for key, value in enumerate(fields):
                if self.field_filter(key, value):
                    record.add(value)
        return record

    def _get_next(self):
        if self._openfile is None:
            raise FileNotOpenException

        if self.max_lines is not None and self.lines >= self.max_lines:
            raise StopIteration

        line = next(self._openfile).rstrip()
        fields = self._compiled_fs.split(line)

        record = self._get_record(fields)

        self.lines += 1

        if not self.record_filter(self.lines, record):
            return None

        return record

    def __next__(self):
        record = self._get_next()
        while record is None:
            # skip filtered out lines
            record = self._get_next()
        return record


class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self,
                 filename,
                 fs=DEFAULT_FIELD_SEP,
                 header=False,
                 max_lines=None,
                 field_func=_DEFAULT_FIELD_FUNC,
                 record_func=_DEFAULT_RECORD_FUNC,
                 field_pre_filter=_DEFAULT_FIELD_FILTER,
                 record_pre_filter=_DEFAULT_RECORD_FILTER,
                 field_post_filter=_DEFAULT_FIELD_FILTER,
                 record_post_filter=_DEFAULT_RECORD_FILTER):
        """Initialise a Parser
        Arguments:
        filename -- the name of the file to parse
        Keyword arguments:
        fs -- a regex that separates the fields
        header -- if set to True, the parser interprets the first line of the file as a header.
                  In this case every record is returned as a dictionary and every field in the header
                  is used as the key of the corresponding field in the following lines
        max_lines -- the maximum number of lines to parse
        field_func -- a function f(field_key, field) which is applied to every field, field_key is
                      the number of the field if there is no header, the corresponding header key otherwise.
                      default: a function that returns the field
        record_func -- a function f(NR, NF, field) which is applied to every record, NR is the record number
                       NF is the total number of fields in the record.
                       default: a function that returns the record
        field_pre_filter -- a function f(field_key, field) which is applied to the field before `field_func`.
                            If it returns a falsy value, the field is not returned.
                            default: lambda *args: True
        record_pre_filter -- a function f(NR, field) which is applied to the record before `record_func`.
                             If it returns a falsy value, the record is not returned
                             default: lambda *args: True
        field_post_filter -- a function f(field_key, field) which is applied to the field after `field_func`.
                             If it returns a falsy value, the field is not returned.
                             default: lambda *args: True
        record_post_filter -- a function f(NR, field) which is applied to the record after `record_func`.
                              If it returns a falsy value, the record is not returned
                              default: lambda *args: True
        """

        self.filename = filename
        self.header = header
        self.fs = fs
        self.max_lines = max_lines
        self.field_func = field_func
        self.record_func = record_func
        self.field_pre_filter = field_pre_filter
        self.record_pre_filter = record_pre_filter
        self.field_post_filter = field_post_filter
        self.record_post_filter = record_post_filter

    def _parse_fields(self, record):
        new_record = Record()
        for key, field in record:
            new_field = self.field_func(key, field)
            if self.field_post_filter(key, new_field):
                new_record[key] = new_field
        return new_record

    def parse(self):
        """Parse the file provided at initialisation time returns a generator of `Record`s.
        The records returned and the fields in them are the result of the application of
        record_func and field_func respectively.
        Only records respecting the pre and post filters are present, same applies for the fields in each record
        """
        reader_args = (self.filename,
                       self.fs,
                       self.header,
                       self.max_lines,
                       self.field_pre_filter,
                       self.record_pre_filter)

        with Reader(*reader_args) as reader:
            for nr, record in enumerate(reader, 1):  # line numbers start from 1
                record = self.record_func(nr, self._parse_fields(record))
                if self.record_post_filter(nr, record):
                    yield record


class Column(object):

    def __init__(self,
                 filename,
                 fs=DEFAULT_FIELD_SEP,
                 header=False,
                 max_lines=None,
                 field_func=lambda x: x,
                 column_func=lambda x: x):
        """
        Initialise a Column object.
        Arguments:
        filename -- the name of the file to parse
        Keyword arguments:
        fs -- a regex that separates the fields
        header -- if set to True, the parser interprets the first line of the file as a header.
                  In this case the columns can be indexed as the key specified in the header and the first
                  element of the column is the header
        max_lines -- the maximum number of lines to parse
        field_func -- a function f(field) which is applied to every field. Default: a function that returns the field
        column_func -- a function f(column) which is applied to every clumn before returning it.
                       Default: a function that returns the field
        """
        self.filename = filename
        self.fs = fs
        self.header = header
        self.max_lines = max_lines
        self.field_func = field_func
        self.column_func = column_func

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        if index is a slice, it returns a tuple of columns, where each column is the result
        of the application of `column_func()` on the column. If `header` is True, `index`
        must be a key in the header, otherwise it can be an integer. In those cases, the result
        of the application of `column_func()` on the single column is returned. `field_func()`
        is applied to every field in the column(s).
        In the case of slicing, indexes start from 0 to make slicing simpler. Please note that this function needs
        to parse the whole file unless max_lines is specified in the constructor
        """

        parser = Parser(self.filename,
                        self.fs,
                        self.header,
                        max_lines=self.max_lines,
                        field_func=lambda key, field: self.field_func(field))

        if isinstance(index, slice):
            columns = OrderedDict()
            for record in parser.parse():
                for i, field in enumerate(list(record.fields())[index]):
                    try:
                        columns[i].append(field)
                    except KeyError:
                        columns[i] = [field]
            # post-processing
            return [self.column_func(tuple(column)) for column in columns.values()]
        else:
            column = []
            for record in parser.parse():
                try:
                    fields = list(record.fields())[index]
                    column.append(fields)
                except IndexError:
                    column.append(None)
            return self.column_func(tuple(column))

    def get(self, *keys):
        """
        returns a generator of tuples where every element in the tuple is the field of the corresponding
        column. For example, if passed three keys, every tuple will have three elements.
        Please note that this function needs to parse the whole file unless max_lines is specified in
        the constructor
        """
        parser = Parser(self.filename,
                        self.fs,
                        self.header,
                        field_pre_filter=lambda key, field: key in keys)
        for record in parser.parse():
            yield tuple(record.fields())
```

Some usage examples (you can find more in [the docs](https://github.com/SimoneBronzini/awk)). Examples assume the following file, called `testinput`.

```
A B C D E F G
2 8 0 0 5 7 7
3 0 7 0 0 7 0
2 3 5 6 6 6 8
0 2 1 0 8 3 7
```

Simple reader:

```
from awk import Reader
with Reader('testinput') as reader:
    for record in reader:
        print(record)
```

Output:

```
Record($1: A, $2: B, $3: C, $4: D, $5: E, $6: F, $7: G)
Record($1: 2, $2: 8, $3: 0, $4: 0, $5: 5, $6: 7, $7: 7)
Record($1: 3, $2: 0, $3: 7, $4: 0, $5: 0, $6: 7, $7: 0)
Record($1: 2, $2: 3, $3: 5, $4: 6, $5: 6, $6: 6, $7: 8)
Record($1: 0, $2: 2, $3: 1, $4: 0, $5: 8, $6: 3, $7: 7)
```

Reader with a header:

```
from awk import Reader
with Reader('testinput', header=True) as reader:
    for record in reader:
        print(record)
```

Output:

```
Record(A: 2, B: 8, C: 0, D: 0, E: 5, F: 7, G: 7)
Record(A: 3, B: 0, C: 7, D: 0, E: 0, F: 7, G: 0)
Record(A: 2, B: 3, C: 5, D: 6, E: 6, F: 6, G: 8)
Record(A: 0, B: 2, C: 1, D: 0, E: 8, F: 3, G: 7)
# a field can be accessed as: record[0], record['$1'], record['A']
# slicing is also supported: record[1:5:2]
```

This makes every record the sum of its squared fields:

```
from awk import Parser
parser = Parser('testinput',
                header=True,
                field_func=lambda key, field: int(field)**2,
                record_func=lambda nr, nf, record: sum(record.values()))
for record in parser.parse():
    print(record)
```

Output:

```
191
107
210
127
```

Simple Column usage:

```
from awk import Column
columns = Column('testinput')
print(list(columns[3]))
```

Output:

```
('D', '0', '0', '6', '0')
```

Column with header:

```
from awk import Column
columns = Column('testinput', header=True)
for line in columns.get('A', 'C', 'E'):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
('2', '0', '5')
('3', '7', '0')
('2', '5', '6')
('0', '1', '8')
```

Comment: @Graipher I have added some examples from the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concept

In many ways, the functionality of this library resembles that of the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.  The main difference is that here you split by regex rather than on a specific character.  I think that the design would be improved by modelling your code after the `csv` module — for example, by having a separate `Reader` and `DictReader`.

The fact that the `Reader` accepts a **`filename`** as input limits the applicability of this code.  What if I want to parse data coming from a network stream?  It can't be done without first writing to a temporary file.

The **field numbering convention** is very confusing in my opinion:

> ```
> """
> - record['$4']  # same as record[3]
> """
> ```

`record['$0']` doesn't retrieve the original text as I would expect.

You should either give up the AWK-inspired `'$4'` notation (for which I don't see much value) or fully embrace the one-based column numbering (which does have some precedent in Python [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group)).

The **filter functions** make the `Parser` do much more than parsing, violating the Single Responsibility Principle.  In addition, the filtering makes it unclear how record numbering works, or what you mean by the "next" record.  I think you would be better off dropping the feature, since Python's generator expressions offer much of the same functionality.

### Iterators

Your iterator implementation is more complicated than necessary, and in fact wrong.

Here's how iterators should behave:

```
>>> words = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()
>>> iter1 = iter(words)
>>> iter2 = iter(words)
>>> next(iter1)
'The'
>>> next(iter1)
'quick'
>>> next(iter1)
'brown'
>>> next(iter2)
'The'
```

However, if I ask for two iterators on the same `Record`, they actually interfere with each other:

```
>>> from awk import Reader
>>> with Reader('fox.txt') as reader:
...     record = next(reader)
... 
>>> str(record)
'Record($1: The, $2: quick, $3: brown, $4: fox, $5: jumps, $6: over, $7: the, $8: lazy, $9: dog)'
>>> iter1 = iter(record)
>>> iter2 = iter(record)
>>> next(iter1)
('$1', 'The')
>>> next(iter1)
('$2', 'quick')
>>> next(iter1)
('$3', 'brown')
>>> next(iter2)
('$4', 'fox')
```

To support iteration, you didn't need to write a `__next__` method; all you needed was this:

```
class Record:
    …

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return an iterator over the record's keys"""
        return ((key, self._field_dict[key]) for key in self._key_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great insight! You implementation of the iterator is definitely the correct one, I will soon change the code to comply with it. As for the indexing, I think you are right, but here is the reasoning: initially I wanted to have indexes starting from 1, so that `record['$3'] is record[3]` but then I wanted to add the slicing feature but I thought that it would have been pretty confusing with indexes starting from 1. So, as a compromise, I decided to keep the "awk notation" for the default keys and keepthe integer indexes starting from 0. (continues on next comment)

Comment: (continues from previous comment) Do you have an idea on how to handle indexes starting from 1 but making slicing not completely counterintuitive?
As for the other suggestions (taking something that is not a filename as input and removing filters from the `Parser`), I will indeed look into them. I'll probably mark this as the accepted answer but I would rather wait a bit and see if other detailed answers arrive!

Comment: Why is the `record['$3']` notation important to you? Do you have a use case to demonstrate how it is useful?

Comment: yeah, right, I forgot to address this point, as a future development I would like to build the Record so that `record['$0']` is the whole line. That takes quite a bit of refactoring at the moment but I think it would be useful

Comment: Yes, I know that's how AWK works, but you still haven't explained _why_ you want to make Python behave like AWK. If you insist on one-based numbering, then perhaps you could use `record.awk_var('$3')` or `record.awk_var(3)` to avoid the zero-based semantics that the `[]` operator implies.

Comment: I would like it to behave like that just becuse this is thought to be an awk-like file manipulation tool, so I guess that someone who wants to use it is used with that kind of numbering and would find it useful. But, of course, this is not necessarily a strong motivation for this behaviour.